# Casting/dereferencing member variable pointer from void*, is this safe?

Tags: c++

I had a problem while hacking a bigger project so I made a simpel test case. If I'm not omitting something, my test code works fine, but maybe it works accidentally so I wanted to show it to you and ask if there are any pitfalls in this approach.

I have an OutObj which has a member variable (pointer) InObj. InObj has a member function. I send the address of this member variable object (InObj) to a callback function as void*. The type of this object never changes so inside the callback I recast to its original type and call the aFunc member function in it. In this exampel it works as expected, but in the project I'm working on it doesn't. So I might be omitting something or maybe there is a pitfall here and this works accidentally. Any comments? Thanks a lot in advance.

(The problem I have in my original code is that InObj.data is garbage).

```
#include <stdio.h>

class InObj
{
public:
 int data;
 InObj(int argData);
 void aFunc()
 {
  printf("Inside aFunc! data is: %d\n", data);
 };
};

InObj::InObj(int argData)
{
 data = argData;
}

class OutObj
{
public:
 InObj* objPtr;
 OutObj(int data);
 ~OutObj();
};

OutObj::OutObj(int data)
{
 objPtr = new InObj(data);
}

OutObj::~OutObj()
{
 delete objPtr;
}

void callback(void* context)
{
 ((InObj*)context)->aFunc();
}

int main ()
{
 OutObj a(42);
 callback((void*)a.objPtr);
}
```

Comment: at a glance, it looks fine.  Define "doesn't work" in your app.

Comment: What is the exact problem that you face in your project?

Comment: The problem I have in my original code is that InObj.data is garbage. So if this looks ok, I should get some sleep and find the obvious bug in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.

A pointer to any type can be converted to a pointer to void and back again.

Note that the conversion *to* `void*` is implicit, so you don't need the cast.

Comment: All pointers are the same size and contain the same data right? The types are just to remind you.

Comment: @Brendan Long: That's not necessarily true. If you have multiple inheritance hierarchies, a pointer cast may involve actually modifying the pointer to point to the correct vtbl structure.

Comment: @Brendan:  There are a lot of intricacies with pointers.  Pointers to members may not have the same size as pointers to objects.  One of guaranteed "will work" things is that if you have a pointer to some object of type `T`, you can convert a `T*` to a `void*` and then back to a `T*` and the original `T*` and the resulting `T*` will point to the same object.  That's the rule that's really important for this question.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea it was so complicated.

Comment: @Brendan:  That's the best part of C++:  even the "simple" things are complicated :-D

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted should be "safe" insofar as a non type safe operation like this can be safe. I would replace the casts you have though with `static_cast` instead of C style casts, because `static_cast` doesn't allow you to make such unsafe conversions between types. If you try to do something unsafe with `static_cast` the compiler will tell you instead of leaving you guessing.

(Side unrelated note: InObj's constructor should use initialization rather than assignment:

```
InObj::InObj(int argData) : data(argData)
{
}
```

)